# Getting App To Wait A Few Seconds Java

Tags: java, android, loops, wait

I am currently writing a game and would like the app to wait a certain amount of time before proceeding. I have tried the sleep function and it does not do what I would like it to. I have a loop for ten and in that I would like one of the text boxes to have its value changed ten times with a couple of seconds gap between each one. So far I have this

```
for(int coolRan = 0; coolRan < 11; coolRan = coolRan + 1) {          
    Random generator = new Random();
    int RanNumGen = generator.nextInt(50) + 1;                          
    String RanNum = Integer.toString(RanNumGen);                
    higherTxt.setText(RanNum);
}
```

What I would like it to do after this is pause for a few seconds before performing the operation in the loop again so in Pseudocode this is what it looks like:

Loop For Ten

Generate Random Number With Maximum Value Of 50

Set A String To Equal The Random Number

Set A TextView To Equal The Random Number

**Wait A Few Seconds**

Perform Operation Again

Comment: How does sleep not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sleep method should work correctly if used in the following way.

```
Thread.sleep();
```

The parameter is the time in milliseconds.

For example:

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
//This pauses or "sleeps" for 5 seconds
```

Comment: I am just a beginner to Java and so have put the code I mentioned in the original post in the onCreate section as I am unsure how to create and call my own public class. I have tried the code you mentioned and all it leaves me with is a blank screen whilst it performs the operation.

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` is likely undesirable in a GUI application, there are generally better ways to delay behavior without locking a thread.

Comment: This cannot be used in Android GUI, will not even run - but if would, would be bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

[`Thread.sleep(long millis)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) makes the currently executing `Thread` sleep for `long` milliseconds (1/1000 seconds).

In Android, sleeping in the UI-thread is very, very bad practice and can for instance lead to a "Application Not Responsive" (ANR) error. To bypass this, you should run it off another thread. There are several ways to do this:

1. Calling [`View.postDelayed(Runnable action, long delayMillis)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) - this will delay it for you so you do not need to call `sleep()`.
2. Making the task implement [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29)
3. Creating a new `Thread` (or `Runnable`) Java-style and then publishing it to the UI-thread with another `Runnable` (yeah.. not recommended) with [`Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Also note that your for-loop will run 11 times, from 0 up to 10 (both inclusive) - not 10 times.